# iOS: Get the real position of current objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uipangesturerecognizer

With the Pan GestureComponent, I am trying to get the first location of the current object dragged. For that, I did:

Firstable, I store the position of the button when State Began.

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

    CGPoint startlocation;

// Get Position X and Y
if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    startlocation = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"%f" @"-" @"%f", startlocation.x , startlocation.y);
}
```

And when the user release the boutton (State Ended), I want to set the button back at the first place.

```
// Quand on lache le composant : Action de fin
if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{     
NSLog(@"%f" @"-" @"%f", startlocation.x , startlocation.y); 
recognizer.view.center = startLocation;  
}
```

NSLog:

State Began:

```
76.000000-158.000000
```

State endend:

```
0.000000--1.998666
```

I have a problem. My button is outSide my screen. I don't know why X and Y of startLocation are modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about 2 different things:

1. The position of the touch that is triggering the pan gesture `recognizer locationInView`
2. The position of the view (you don't say if you're using the frame origin or the center)

It isn't clear what you're trying to do but you need to decide, are you moving the target view by the pan gesture translation:

```
if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
   startLocation = targetView.center;
}

CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];

CGPoint newCenter = startLocation;
newCenter.x += translation.x;
newCenter.y += translation.y;

targetView.center = newCenter;
```

or you're trying to snap the target view to the pan gesture location

```
targetView.center = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
```

This is all assuming that the target view is a direct subview of self.view...

Comment: My level is not so advanced to understand all the differences that you are talking about, but basically I have a button on my Iview. I want to move it over the screen area. When the user drags the button, above all, I need to store the location of my button (x and y). And when the user drops the button, anywhere, I want to set  my button back at the first place.

Comment: So, the user starts panning from the button, the button redraws as they move, under their finger, then when they release is goes back to where it started (and you store the end position)?

Comment: yes almost, but I just need to store the first position. Not the end :) ...

(saving the first position, will be able me, to set the button at the first place)

Comment: In the code in my answer, the target view is your button. startLocation records the center of the button when the user starts panning on it. The code below (using locationInView) updates the position of the button to the position of the finger on the screen. You can add a section for the gesture completing and use the startLocation to put the button back.

Comment: If I catch well, I used your code and I added: if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    { [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(startLocation.x, startLocation.y)  inView:self.view];} But it's not exactly the correct position when I release the button. :( Have I a mistake?

Comment: Why do you want to set the translation of the gesture recogniser? You stated that you want to set the position of the button (targetView.center = startLocation).

Comment: ? But I have not the current object as explicit (button), it's dynamic. Please, check my declaration: - (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{...}

When you said: "targetView.center = startLocation;" I translate it with : "recognizer.view.center = startLocation;" Because that's only the component that I have in my method. Wrong??

Comment: No, that's fine. I'm not sure why you're doing: [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(startLocation.x, startLocation.y) inView:self.view] as there doesn't seem to be a purpose.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. I have updated the first topic. I guessed that "recognizer" in the declaration means the "current button" and when I put : [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(startLocation.x, startLocation.y) inView:self.view] I was trying the set the button back. But I wrong ... I don't really understand how can I do 'cause for me, and many others topic, the declaration parameter of the method seems correct. As you explain yourself correctly before, I just want to move the button at the first place, when the user release it.

Comment: ps: And I don't have in my method the explicit declaration of the button because it's dynamic. I have only one method for several buttons. So I can not declare explicitly button1.center = startLocation;

Comment: recognizer.view is the button. So recognizer.view.center = startLocation; is correct. Update your question with your new code and a new description of what doesn't work if you still have problems.

Comment: I know. - (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{ is always call for all actions then the variable is always instantiated. So I have to declare it as Static and the problem is solved. The position is better. In the log I keep the exact position, but I the screen the position of the button are not exactly in the same first place (an offset of 20 pixels.).

Comment: Don't use static, make startLocation an instance variable and use self.startLocation.